# C# Use instantiated class in a different class/file

Tags: c#, class, instance

Am I able to use an instance of once class in another class and file without having to reinstantiate it?

```
class Start
{
    public static Log Log = new Log(...);
}

class Start1
{
    Log.Write("New instance!");
}
```

I have read about having to use a `get/set` block to do it, but I'm not exactly sure how I would go about that,

Comment: `Start.Log.Write(...)`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too basic

Comment: @AndreyNasonov - read the code again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Singleton pattern:

```
  public class Log
        {
            private static Log instance;

            private Log() { }

            public static Log Instance
            {
                get           
                {
                    return instance ?? (instance = new Log());              
                }
            }
        }
```

Use it by calling Log.Instance, and so on.

To call this using a parameter, you need to do something like this:

```
   public class Log
        {
            private string foo;

            private static Log instance;

            public static Log Instance
            {
                get
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Call CreateInstance(-) to create this object");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return instance;
                    }
                }
            }

            private Log(string foo) { this.foo = foo; }

            public static Log CreateInstance(string foo)
            {
                return instance ?? (instance = new Log(foo));
            }
        }
```

However, it is generally a bad idea to use singletons in this manor. Have a look at dependency injection / inversion of control to see how this can be solved.

Comment: How would I change this to be able to pass in arguments to `new Log();`? Other than that it works perfectly, but I need args passed in or it will crash my app.

Comment: In general, singletons are usually a bad idea, especially if you pass parameters in to the constructor, it's all about guaranteeing that only one of these types will be used in your application, etc. However, there is nothing stopping you from adding a public Write(string foo) method in the singleton class. You would use this like Log.Instance.Write("New Instance"); for example. You could look at other patterns to, i.e. inversion of control / dependency injection.

Comment: I need to pass arguments into the constructor, not the methods (well I do, but that works already).